# Webpack + ts-loader fails on stage 3 decorators: Unexpected character '@'

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

The following code:

```
const decorator = (constructor: any, _context: any) => constructor

@decorator
export class Decorated {}
```

fails in Webpack + ts-loader with the message: Unexpected character '@'

Relevant part of webpack config:

```
rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                resolve: {
                    extensionAlias: {
                        ".js": [".ts"]
                    }
                }
            }
]
```

This seems to be a problem in ts-loader, because if `experimentalDecorators` is enabled it does know what to do with that syntax. It still fails because that flag enables an older decorator proposal. The new (stage 3) proposal is supported since TypeScript 5.

I find it strange that no one seems to have encountered this issue, so I'm assuming that I'm making some silly mistake. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce your issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-terser-uvczrw?file=src%2Findex.ts,tsconfig.json,dist%2Fmain.bundle.js,webpack.config.js) or on the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99&jsx=0&allowUnreachableCode=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgU1AJwIZRMmBeGAKUSKZAV2A2QC4ZUwBPAGhgH1CoEAPKa2ugShwA%20GAG8AUDEkxCEEABsEAOjkgA5ngDkiFOkwaBUiVOQIoJZGGnhopcpjEBfANxixAAW2ZdyMcDmoICBgAESQvdjhRBzEgA).

In your `tsconfig.json`, change `useDefineForClassFields` to `false` and it should work !

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you explain why this solves it?

Comment: My only guess is that while decorator have been defined and reached stage 3, they are not implemented. (try running one in your browser console, it just don't work).

Comment: I had same issue with `parcel` and `@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc`. And I've had `ES2022` as target, where `useDefineForClassFields` defaults to `true`. Still, I don't understand what this has to do with parsing of `@myDecorator` syntax. But it solved the issue for me as well.